# Problems with loop Erreur dans parse(text = expr1) : <text>:2:0: fin d'entrée inattendu(e)

Tags: r, parsing, loops, eval

Hy everybody.

Beginner trying to understand a loop. Here is the script I try to use:

```
## List of species
vctsp <- levels(data.baobab$Species)`
nspecies <- length(vcstp)` 
absp <- c("Ad","Ab","Ax","An","Al","Ap","Ac","Ar")` 

## Loop on species
for (i in 1:nspecies) {
  expr <- paste("data.",absp[i], <- data.baobab[data.baobab$Species==\"",vctsp[i],"\",]",sep="") 
  eval(parse(text=expr))
}

## Stack World Clim Data
myExpl_37 <- stack("./gis.data/bio_37/bio1_37.tif",
                   "./gis.data/bio_37/bio4_37.tif",
                   "./gis.data/bio_37/bio12_37.tif")
```

Here occurs the problem:

```
for (i in 1: nspecies) { 
  expr1 <- paste("clim.", absp [i], " <- extract(myExpl_37, data.baobab[data.baobab$Species==\"",vctsp[i],"\",]",sep="")
  eval(parse(text=expr1))
}

Erreur dans parse(text = expr1) : <text>:2:0: fin d'entrée inattendu(e)
1: clim.Ad <- extract(myExpl_37,data.baobab[data.baobab$Species=="A_digitata",]^`
```

This loop should be like this (if I did it manually):

```
clim.Az <- extract(myExpl_37,data.Az)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating code using string manipulation, it's always a good idea to print out the code to make sure it come out right. In this case:

```
cat(expr1)
# clim.Ad <- extract(myExpl_37, data.baobab[data.baobab$Species=="A_diitata",]
```

Notice the missing `)` at the end?

You need to have `"\",])"` where you have `"\",]"` at the moment.